# iphonesdk facebook image sharing

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

i used code in this project to post images on facebook 6 months ago, today i try to use it again but this code doesnot posting my photos on facebook. any one knows what issue this projects has and why it is not posting images???

```
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app
```

thanks in advance

Comment: i just ask a question, if you dont have answer why you vote down for me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-(void)checkForAccessToken:(NSString *)urlString {

```
NSUInteger loc1 = NSNotFound;
NSUInteger loc2 = NSNotFound;
NSString *accessStr = @"access_token=";
if ((loc1 = [urlString rangeOfString:accessStr].location) != NSNotFound && (loc2 = [urlString rangeOfString:@"&"].location) != NSNotFound){
    if (loc1 + [accessStr length] < loc2){
        if((loc2  - loc1-[accessStr length]) < [urlString length]){
            NSUInteger test = [accessStr length];
            NSString *accessToken = [urlString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(loc1 +test , loc2 - loc1 - test)];
            [_delegate accessTokenFound:accessToken];
        }
    }

}
```

ok i found out what was need to update in that code, we need to just update this function and all will work again.... posting the code for anyone who suffers the same problem.